# Python: Regex & group(0) errors parsing Git History

Tags: python, regex, git

The goal here is to capture Git log information for which the following code is functional *except* for capturing files added or modified (see section 'for j in commit'):

```
import re
import git
import time
import datetime

repo = git.Repo('/path/to/repo')

data = repo.git.log('--name-status')
data = "\n" + data
data=re.split("\ncommit ",data)
data.pop(0)
commits_list = list(repo.iter_commits())
MM = []

for i in data:
    commit = i.split('\n')
    chash = commit[0]
    author = re.search('Author:.*\n', i).group(0)
    author = re.sub(r'\<.*\>\n','',author)
    author = author.strip()
    email = re.search(('<.*>'),i).group(0)
    email = re.sub(r'[\<\>]','',email)
    date = re.search('Date:.*\n', i).group(0)
    date = re.sub(r'[\n]','',date)
    tzone = re.search('-.*', date).group(0)
    tzone = re.sub(r'[\n]','',tzone)
    date = re.sub(r'-.*','',date)
    date = re.sub(r'Date:   ','',date.strip())
    date = datetime.datetime.strptime(date, "%c")
    date = date.strftime('%s')
    files = []
    for j in commit:
        k = (re.search(r'A\t.*$|M\t.*$', i)).group(0)
        if k:
            files.append(k)

    L = [chash,author,email,date,tzone,files]
    print L
    MM.append(L)
```

This results in an `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'` but if I move the grouping to the if statement (ie, `files.append(k.group(0))`) then I get a repeat of the same file as if the loop in executing for each line. I also attempted a try/except in the loop with similar results. What am I not getting?

**UPDATE**

Changed/corrected the loop to:

```
for j in commit:
  try:
   k = (re.search(r'A\t.*$|M\t.*$', j)).group(0)
   files.append(k)
  except:
   None
```

I get a repeat of the same file name for each file committed.

Comment: Can you provide an example of what's in `i` and what your output is?

Comment: Please indent your code by four spaces. Single-space indented code is not very readable.

Answer (score 1):

In this line, should `i` actually be `j` ?

```
k = (re.search(r'A\t.*$|M\t.*$', i)).group(0)
```

Comment: This is probably why my try/except failed! Validating....nope: I get "None" for everything.

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR: you are getting failures to match your regular expression.

---

This is more a Python question than a Git question.  However:

> ```
> for j in commit:
>     k = (re.search(r'A\t.*$|M\t.*$', i)).group(0)
> ```

seems rather nonsensical.  Let's look at the inputs.

First, the variable `i` is bound to a string due to the outer:

> ```
> for i in data:
> ```

where `data` comes from splitting a big chunk of text at `"\ncommit "` boundaries.  This string might have a form like this (I have modified it very slightly):

```
>>> i = bigarray[1]
>>> print bigarray[1]
238e487ea943f80734cc6dad665e7238b8cbc7ff
Author: Junio C Hamano <gitster pobox.com>
Date:   Sat Aug 26 23:00:01 2017 -0700

    The fifth batch post 2.14

    Signed-off-by: Junio C Hamano <gitster pobox.com>

M   Documentation/RelNotes/2.15.0.txt
```

You then do:

> ```
> commit = i.split('\n')
> ```

so that `commit` contains each of the various lines of the above text.

This means that:

```
for j in commit:
```

iterates over each line; but then you do:

```
k = re.search(pattern, i).group(0)
```

This searches the original, un-split lines for the pattern, repeatedly, once for each line resulting from splitting at newlines.

Now, the regular-expression pattern for which you are searching does occur in this particular text in `i` (from the big array you call `data`, which I have in my variable `bigarray`.  But some entries might not have any occurrences of your pattern.  For instance:

```
>>> print bigarray[2]
6e6ba65a7c8f8f9556ec42678f661794d47f7f98
Merge: eabdcd4ab 9d89b3552
Author: Junio C Hamano <gitster pobox.com>
Date:   Sat Aug 26 22:55:10 2017 -0700

    Merge branch 'mg/killed-merge'

    Killing "git merge --edit" before the editor returns control left
    the repository in a state with MERGE_MSG but without MERGE_HEAD,
    which incorrectly tells the subsequent "git commit" that there was
    a squash merge in progress.  This has been fixed.

    * mg/killed-merge:
      merge: save merge state earlier
      merge: split write_merge_state in two
      merge: clarify call chain
      Documentation/git-merge: explain --continue
```

This particular commit has no `A` or `M` files listed in its `--name-status`.  This is because it is a merge commit and `git log` ignores its diff entirely by default (but there exist other commits that only delete files, or only rename files, or only have status-changes, and so on; one cannot count on every diff containing an `A` or `M` line).

(It's also not a good idea to apply this search to the log *message*, since that might quote a bit of Git output and hence *resemble* actual `--name-status` output for a commit, without being such output.  But that is a separate problem.)

In any case, if `re.search` cannot find a match, it returns `None`.  The `None` object does not have a `group` attribute: `None.group(0)` causes the error.

Your "update" code adds a rather brutal "ignore all exceptions" clause.  This captures the `AttributeError` that occurs when trying to access `None.group`.  It does not fix the major underlying problems of scanning the entire `git log` text multiple times (once per line) to find the first matching `A` or `M` line within it.

As [Austin Hastings suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46179076/1256452), it *might* make sense to loop through all the lines, checking each one.  But that still leaves you `re.search`ing everything in the `git log` output, including the author and log message.  Since those lines are indented by default, you could take advantage of that with an *anchored* search: match `A` or `M` only in the first column, using `re.match` or a `^` in your search pattern.

(There are many more alternatives of course, including parsing the known output format: commit hash, `Merge` line if present, and so on; or using `--pretty=` directives to *control* the format.  Also consider whether you want to look at combined diffs from merges, but note that their statuses look different: run `git log --cc` to see.)